# Problem with merging 2 csv files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 very big `csv` files and trying to merge them using `pandas`. here is what I did:

```
AP_PP = pd.read_csv('AP_PP.csv')

AP_NN = pd.read_csv('AP_NN.csv')

merged_df = pd.merge(AP_PP, AP_NN, on='external', how='inner')
```

but when I looked at the dimension of each file and merged dataframe, the number of rows is not as expected. here is the expected dimension:

```
[17624 rows x 2305 columns]
```

and here is what I got:

```
AP_PP:

[17624 rows x 289 columns]

AP_nn:

[17624 rows x 2017 columns]

merged_df:

[52038 rows x 2305 columns]
```

do you know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

also when I print 2 input files I see "`NaN`" in column `external` which is being used for merging. how can I remove the rows with `NaN` at the same time that I merge 2 files?

Comment: AP_PP = pd.read_csv('AP_NN.csv') , is this typo error ?

Comment: @yashaswi k : corrected now.

Comment: @user3925736 If the answers were helpful and fixed your issue, don't forget to upvote and accept those answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, by dropping `Nan` values before merging,

```
pd.merge(AP_PP.dropna(subset=['external']), 
         AP_NN.dropna(subset=['external']), 
         how='inner', on='external')
```